# How to get GitHub pages to serve my images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, github-pages, package.json

I made a react app (not using create react app) using web pack. I managed to get it to GitHub pages by building it to a "build" folder and using the gh-pages module. However, on the gh-pages module, even though it seems the images are present, they won't show up.

https://github.com/harry-z-huang/restaurant-v2.git

[image: inspect image of deployed website]

Additionally, if anyone has any advice on how to deploy a web pack app properly, that would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure my method by building it into a build folder is wrong, but building to the root like some solutions suggest doesn't work.

Here is my package json

```
"name": "reactappscratch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://harry-z-huang.github.io/restaurant-v2/",
  "repository": {
    "url": "git+https://harry-z-huang.github.io/restaurant-v2/"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch src --exec 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --open'",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pg": "^8.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.10",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my web pack config

```
onst path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The images serve when I run "npm start" on local host, but it doesn't work on GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the built-in [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for [Loading Images](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images)
2. There are `public` and `build` directories in your project. It seems duplicated, we keep the `public` as the directory for bundle files, and remove the `build` directory.
3. Use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to simplify creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
4. Create a `images` directory in the `src` directory and move the images from the `public` directory to it. Since we use the asset module handle our images, we need to use `const MyImage = require('./src/images/DSC04213.JPG')` to load the image.

> That image will be processed and added to your output directory and the `MyImage` variable will contain the final URL of that image after processing.

So, change the value of `image` property in `Database.js` file from to below:

`Database.js`:

```js
  {
    id: 1,
    engName: "Gyoza",
    engDescription: "Korean dumplings made with pork",
    korName: "Gyoza",
    korDescription: "Some korean words here",
    price: 10.99,
    allergy: "",
    spice: 0,
    image: require("./src/images/DSC04218.JPG"),
  },
  // others are same
]
```

After building, the project structure is:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── Database.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── 52a2ed3e6d0aaeb9d35c.JPG
│   ├── 6f929b36d64904f2a8a8.JPG
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.411c363b8dc4e906dc55.js
│   └── main.411c363b8dc4e906dc55.js.LICENSE.txt
├── server.js
├── src
│   ├── app
│   ├── components
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

npm scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --watch src --exec 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --open'",
  "build": "webpack --mode production",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d public"
},
```

Deploy:

```
> gh-pages -d public

Published
```

[image]

The URL of the image is like this: `https://mrdulin.github.io/restaurant-v2/52a2ed3e6d0aaeb9d35c.JPG`

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/restaurant-v2